# standard destructor when a destructor is redefined

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor

Is it possible to call the default destructor even if I have redefined a destructor for a class in C++? for example if I have two classes

```
class B{
  ...
};

class A{
private:
   B* p;
public:
   A(B b):p(new B(b)){...}
   ...
   ~A(){delete p;}
};
```

and I don't always want to delete the object pointed by p.

Comment: Your example makes no sense.  Why would you _not_ want to delete the `p`?

Comment: FYI `delete nullptr;` is legal and guaranteed to do nothing.  So you might want `p = nullptr;`

Comment: @MooingDuck: If you transferred ownership of the memory to another component, perhaps?

Comment: You can have some class member bool such as doDeleteB as a condition to delete in the deconstructor... but why would you want to?

Comment: Yes, you're allowed to delete a pointer object by redefining the destructor of the class that pointer object is declared in. You don't have to redefine the destructor of the pointer object in order to do this.

Comment: @Poriferous: That won't prevent freeing the memory.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming by "standard destructor" you mean the one your compiler would have generated by default, **the answer is no**. Because you defined your own destructor, the compiler simply does not generate a default one. Destructors aren't meant to be "called" like a normal function anyway (unless you're implementing something like an STL container).

If you need your destructor to do different things under different circumstances, put an if() in the destructor, and have the object keep track of whatever information it needs for the if() condition. That's probably a better design anyway.

Answer (score 2):

A destructor has only 1 possible signature, so you can't define multiple versions.